# Aggregate sum with lookup to another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two schemas, one is `User` the other is `Pet`. The `Pet` schema has information that I want to `$sum` inside the `User.aggregate` pipeline.

Mongo version is 3.4.1.

**User schema:**

```
pets: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pets'}]
```

**Pets schema:**

```
      owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
      petLost: {
       lost            : {type: Boolean, default: false},
       lostDate        : {type: String},
       selectedComRange: {type: Number, default: 5},
       circumstances   : {type: String},
       extraInfoLost   : {type: String},
       rewardCheck     : {type: Boolean, default: false},
       reward          : {type: String},
       addressLost     : {type: String},
      }
```

This is the lookup:

```
{'$unwind': '$pets'},
    {
      '$lookup': {
        'from'        : 'pets',
        'localField'  : '_id',
        'foreignField': '_id',
        'as'          : 'lostPets'
      }
    },
{'$unwind': {path: '$lostPets', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}}
```

And here's the condition i'm trying to achieve:

```
'lostPet_count': {
          '$sum': {
            '$cond': [{'$eq': ['$lostPets.lost', true]}, 1, 0]
          }
        }
```

**Aggregate pipeline:**

```
User.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id              : null,
            'users_count'    : {
              '$sum': {
                '$cond': [{'$eq': ['$role', 'user']}, 1, 0]
              }
            },
            'volunteer_count': {
              '$sum': {
                '$cond': [{'$eq': ['$isVolunteer', true]}, 1, 0]
              }
            },
            'pet_count'      : {
              '$sum': {
                $size: '$pets'
              }
            },
            'lost_pet'       : {
              '$sum': {
                **// how can i call another collection and $sum some data?**
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          '$project': {
            '_id'       : 0, 'role': '$_id',
            'statistics': {
              'users'     : '$users_count',
              'volunteers': '$volunteer_count',
              'pets'      : '$pet_count'
            }
          }
        }
      ]).exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        res.status(200).json(result);
      });
```

How can I inject info into `'lost_pet'` property from the Pet schema ?

Comment: take a look at [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: @felix that's what I'm doing now, if I manage to do it I'll post back the results

Comment: when i try to unwind the array with ` { '$unwind': '$pets'},` i get this error: `MongoError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: objectId
`  
---
This is the schema type: `pets                : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pets'}],`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following pipeline should return the desired results:

```
Pets.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users',
            'localField': 'owner',
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'as': 'users'
        }
    },
    { '$unwind': { 'path': '$users', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$users._id',
            'users_count': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': [{'$eq': ['$users.role', 'user']}, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            'volunteer_count'   : {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': ['$users.isVolunteer', 1, 0]
                }
            },
            'pet_count': { '$sum': 1 },
            'lost_pets': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': ['$petLost.lost', 1, 0]
                }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 0, 'role': '$_id',
            'statistics': {
                'users': '$users_count',
                'volunteers': '$volunteer_count',
                'pets': '$pet_count',
                'lostpets': '$lost_pets'
            }
        }
    }
]).exec((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

---

Or aggregating from the `User` model as

```
User.aggregate([
    { '$unwind': '$pets' },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'pets',
            'localField': 'pets',
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'as': 'pets'
        }
    },
    { '$unwind': { 'path': '$pets', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } }
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id',
            'role': { '$first': '$role' },
            'isVolunteer': { '$first': '$isVolunteer' },
            'pet_count': { '$sum': 1 },
            'lost_pets': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': ['$pets.petLost.lost', 1, 0]
                }
            }   
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': null,
            'users_count': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': [{'$eq': ['$role', 'user']}, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            'volunteer_count'   : {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': ['$isVolunteer', 1, 0]
                }
            },
            'pet_count': { '$sum': '$pet_count' },
            'lost_pets': { '$sum': '$lost_pets' }   
        }
    },
    {
      '$project': {
        '_id': 0, 'role': '$_id',
        'statistics': {
            'users': '$users_count',
            'volunteers': '$volunteer_count',
            'pets': '$pet_count',
            'lostpets': '$lost_pets'
        }
      }
    }
]).exec((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

Comment: The user and lostpets are 0. I have user with role `user` and a lost pet set to true. Here's the response: `[
  {
    "role": null,
    "statistics": {
      "users": 0,
      "volunteers": 1,
      "pets": 1,
      "lostpets": 0
    }
  }
]`

edit: users seems to work, lostpets still stays at 0

Comment: You could try aggregating from the `Pets` model as in the above.